# Distribution of Interquartile Range on $X_i$ ∼ U(0, 1), i = 1, . . . , 20, iid.

Tags: probability, statistics, order-statistics

> Let Xi ∼ U(0, 1), i = 1, . . . , 20, iid.
>   IQR = $F^{−1}(.75)−F^{−1}(.25)$ = $X_{(15)}−X_{(5)}$ in this example as n = 20.
>
> a. Find the distribution of the random variable W = IQR.
>
> b. Devise a function of this random variable such that it has expectation of
>   the length of the support of distribution. Do the same thing for the range
>
> c. Consider both of these quantities from (b) as ways to guess (estimate) the
>   length of the support. Compute the relative efficiency (the ratio of mean square
>   errors, it doesn’t matter which is in the numerator) of these two quantities.

I could figure out solution to (a) by using formulas for order statistic, but I'm stuck on (b) and (c). How do I devise such functions of IQR and range? And how do I make use of results from (b) to solve (c)?

Any hint is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to list the result of (a).

Comment: My guess is that it guides you to find the unbiased estimator of 1, i.e. $E[g(W)] = 1$. Usually it is just done by multiplying a constant. It seems more natural if the problem set up is $\text{Uniform}(0, \theta)$ though, then you are really estimating but not just guessing. For part c) it is just similar, once you got both unbiased estimator from the range and IQR, you can compute the MSE and thus the efficiency. The MSE becomes the variance of the estimator when it is unbiased.

Comment: @BGM Thank you, I'll try like that.